# generate_blob_sas creating invalid SAS token

Tags: python, azure, blob

I'm updating some scripts that were using Microsoft's older azure-storage module and switching up the the [`v12`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) SDK.

I'm encountering an issue generating SAS tokens for blobs. Using the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlobServiceClient,
    BlobSasPermissions,
    generate_blob_sas,
)

client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=account_key)
token = generate_blob_sas(
            account_name=client.account_name,
            account_key=client.credential.account_key,
            container_name="tempcontainer",
            blob_name="test.txt",
            permissions=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
            expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1),
        )
```

I receive tokens that look like this:

> se=2021-05-04T01%3A50%3A41Z&sv=2020-06-12&sr=b&sig=___________________________________________%3D

Which when I attempt to use to download the resource returns the following error:

```xml
<Error>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-custom-link"/>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-general-link"/>
  <style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
  <style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-native-style"/>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>
      Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:7c78e0c4-001e-010f-6b7f-40cd26000000 Time:2021-05-04T00:48:24.8329422Z
  </Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>sp is mandatory. Cannot be empty</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Using the same account and credentials, I'm still able to successfully generate SAS tokens using the older version:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, ContainerPermissions

token = self.client.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(
    "tempcontainer",
    "test.txt",
    ContainerPermissions.READ,
    datetime.now() + duration,
)
```

Which produces working tokens, with the "sp" query param being included.

> se=2021-06-03T16%3A57%3A59Z&sp=r&sv=2017-04-17&sr=b& sig=___________________________________________%3D

I've also tested with Azure Storage Explorer to verify that the account/key that I'm using aren't the problem, and I'm able to generate SAS links via that tool as well.

Here's the output of `pip list` and all the azure modules installed in my venv:

```
azure-common                  1.1.25
azure-core                    1.13.0
azure-identity                1.3.1
azure-keyvault-secrets        4.1.0
azure-mgmt-core               1.2.2
azure-mgmt-keyvault           2.2.0
azure-storage-blob            12.8.1
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the new SDK to generate these SAS tokens? Is this somehow a different token, or there's some extra param that I'm missing? Maybe a different/better way to generate SAS tokens with this new version?

Many thanks in advance for any help in this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code using V12 SDK, for `generate_blob_sas` function, the param name should be `permission` instead of `permissions`

This is my test code based on the code you shared:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlobSasPermissions,
    generate_blob_sas
)

token = generate_blob_sas(
            account_name='<account name>',
            account_key='<account key>',
            container_name='<container name>',
            blob_name='<blob name>',
            permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
            expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1),
        )

print(token)
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Embarrassingly simple... Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Comment: @mr.plow glad to help :)