# 413 Request Entity Too Large with IIS

Tags: angular, azure, iis, azure-blob-storage

I am qute new web developer and I am facing a problem with uploading files to Azure file storage. From Angular I am sending a files into Flask backend and from there it is uploaded to Azure. My application is able to transfer small files but with bigger ones like couple of MB I am receiving following error.
`error: "<html>\r\n<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"`
During my resarches I have found that it can be the problem with IIS. So I modified my web.config file to following

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <configuration>
      <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000" executionTimeout="120" />
      </system.web>
     <system.webServer>
       <security>
        <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"  />
        </requestFiltering>
       </security>  
        <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>
   <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't help me. The strange thing is that I am not using nginx but in the error message there is `<center>nginx</center>` and I have no idea why nginx is mentioned there.
I have also found that there is something like HTTP binding but I am not sure which I have and I don't how to check it. Does someone have any idea what can be wrong with my application? Thanks in advance

Comment: FLask backend is probably using nginx so basically the best way would be as Stanley suggested you to use SAS token

Comment: Could you pls kindly accept my post if it works for you? :)

Comment: But to use SAS Token I would need to rebuild my application? Because I would request a SAS token and do whole update via Angular frontend. Maybe I just need to change the nginx settings?

Comment: I am not quite sure if this issue could be solved by configuring Nginx(for uploading large files to storage, I think you also need to modify your FLask backend), but I am sure my solution would work as I have done this before and this is the recommended way for this scenario,otherwise, if there are a lot of users to upload files, your server would face high IO and network pressure

Comment: Ok thanks. If it is recommended I will try your solution. I hope it will works. Previosly I thought that it is better to do all connections in backend. I am only wondering if my SAS token will not be visible in frontend? Is it not dangerous situation?

Comment: I think it is not dangerous as you just granted a blob write permission to the client and you can set SAS token expiring time(in my demo, it will get expired within 1 hour). You can also set the allowed IP address based on the user IP for further security requirements.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: But if I understand correcly everyone who have access to this endpoint will be able to create SAS access token and at list for 1 hour will be able to reach stuff in my storage? I am not sure if I can allow IP addresses beacuse it is possible that will be many of them.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue, your Angular app can request a SAS token with write permission from the Flask backend and use this SAS token to upload a file to Azure storage directly by [JavaScript v12 SDK for browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser).

For how to generate a SAS token by python blob SDK, pls see my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377579/generate-blob-sas-creating-invalid-sas-token/67377689#67377689). In this demo, you should set permission as `permission=BlobSasPermissions(write=True)` for uploading a file to the storage blob.

This way could also greatly ease server IO pressure.

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the app nginx is not used but it is used in kubernetess ingress and there was a need to change the upload_max_filesize setting to bigger value. Default was 1MB